# Getting into grub loader in Ubuntu Virtual Box machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, grub, password-recovery

I have Ubuntu guest OS installed on Virtual Box on windows. But I have forgotten all passwords for user and root accounts. But when I try to get into grub by pressing escape at startup, nothing happens. How do I get into grub loader to change the password? Acually no grub menu is shown when it starts. Is there any other way to reset all the passwords?

Answer (score 1):

You could mount the Ubuntu install ISO image as a CD, boot from CD and go into rescue mode to change all of the passwords, if you wanted.

To attach the ISO image to VirtualBox, go to Settings --> Storage and look for either the CD icon, or click on the CD icon with a plus on it.
[image: Step Onet]
If the ISO image you want isn't there, add it using the Virtual Media Manager.
[image: Step Two]

Press F12 at boot to look at all of the VirtualBox boot options, and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake. Just boot with the cd you installed from. Fire up a text editor and modify the line of /etc/shadow on your root partition for the user root (or your own user) to read:

```
jaroslav:mynotsosecretpassword:9797:0:::::
```

jaroslav is your username, mynotsosecretpassword is your new password. Leave everything else as it is.

Comment: It expects a hashed password not clear text, so putting the password in the field won't work, you need to leave the field empty and then you can log in without a password. I.e.:

jaroslav::9797:0:::::